# Android - PNG file makes bitmap XML unparsable

Tags: android, image, png

I have a single PNG file that when referred from the XML bitmap file will generate `Failed to parse file` error in Eclipse resource editor. When I substitute it with other file everything works. When I run the app - the image will not show up. The XML code is:

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/linen_android_tile"
    android:dither="true"
    android:tileMode="repeat">
</bitmap>
```

And here's the file:

[image: img]

Comment: When I run your code using the PNG you provide on Windows with ADT 15 on an Android 4.0 emulator, things work fine. Maybe imgur alters the image when you upload it so it becomes repaired? Is the md5 sum of the PNG file you see the problems with 2812974ccb6c09b4a59cf40933f02efb? If not, then me and mice are not reproducing the problem with the PNG you see the problem with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also if you're using an indexed png file, try converting it to RGB.

Comment: Displayed is the file in question

Comment: Ok. I downloaded it and cracked it open. The gIMP says it's an indexed png. Convert it to an RGB png. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics

Comment: Thanks Sheridan, that surely did it! Enjoy the bounty!

Answer (score 0):

No problem for me with your PNG.

Solutions:

- Update to Eclipse ADT plugin version 15
- Try to refresh Eclipse res folder
- Save your PNG in 24-bit instead of 8-bit

Comment: I use latest plugin and the error is consistent on 2 different window boxes

Answer (score 0):

Unlikely, but worth checking, the filename isn't `linen_android_tile.9.png` is it?  That indicates a 9-patch png and they are treated differently.

Answer (score 0):

change your png file, may be some internal  problem with your image  file . It happen some time with me also but change the file worked fine for me.